# Add Activities programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to add multiple Activities programmatically in Android.
Can I add these Activities to the manifest  dynamically or is there any other solution in Android?

Comment: For what reason would you need to? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to do that? How about loading different layout in the same activity?

Comment: may be you can use a dummy activity and reuse this by add/remov- ing views according to you need?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot add new activities to your app dynamically or edit the manifest file as this would be a violation of the Android security model. One purpose of the manifest file is that the developer must define which activities are part of the application and what they are allowed to do.

If it were possible to edit this information after the installation of the app on a device, you would be able to execute code the user might never have permitted.

Comment: Do you have any references to this? Thanks

Comment: Just read the Android documentation about signing an apps. Android apps must be signed with a private key before they can be published through Google Play. If you would be able to alter the any of the app's files within the apk file then the signature won't be correct any more and a validation would fail.

Comment: @Flo, are you suggesting I cannot add activity or layout to main activity programmatically using just pure Java? I don't think it has anything to do with app signing.