# Android there is a way to start an application programatically without adding to manifest?

Tags: android, manifest

I would like only to start some applications dynamically with the package name from the app i develop, i already tried this:

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
component = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), myPrefs.getString("Combo1", null));
Log.i("LOG", myPrefs.getString("Combo1", null));
intent.setComponent(component);
```

and

```
intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(myPrefs.getString("Combo1", null));
startActivity(intent);
```

both works and several applications opens but for others i get this error.

```
11-29 21:42:08.723: E/AndroidRuntime(4719): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.lock/com.sec.android.app.phoneutil}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I understand the error(that i need to add the app/activity in manifest), so i want to know if is a workaround to add dynamically activities to manifest, or there is a way to start dynamically an application without adding to the manifest that app/activity, or there is a permission that allow to open applications ?

From my research it seems impossible, but i want to know the opinion of an expert.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374323/add-activities-programmatically-in-android

Comment: i want to make an app that start diff. app dynamically from your phone

Comment: i know that is a solution to override the permissions, but it works only for rooted phones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are talking about launching other apps from yours, this is the code you need:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName,mainActivity));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

You can get the main activity like this:

```
Intent mIntent = ctx.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName); 
if (mIntent != null) {
    if (mIntent.getComponent() != null) {
    mainActivity = mIntent.getComponent().getClassName();
    }
}
```

Comment: on this it give me 11-29 23:13:08.674: E/AndroidRuntime(6652): java.lang.NullPointerException: class name is null

Comment: Hi djcharon, glad it helped. It would be nice to accept the answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not start an activity (screen) without adding it to the manifest! ever!

Always add it!

Answer (score 0):

Intent i = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("applications package name which you want to open");
        context.startActivity(i);