# Android, run a certain shortcut

Tags: android, shortcut

So, there are apps that can create shortcuts on the home screen.
My question is, How can my app opens/runs/starts a certain shortcut?

if I have 2 browser shortcuts, each of them loads a different url ... how can I choose between them? how to choose to open the 1st or the second one?

Comment: Shortcuts are visual cues to an `Intent`. What excatly are you asking?

Comment: look in to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3343531/3326331) or this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8317174/3326331)

Comment: so you want to launch both the url on single click? or on two different clicks?

Answer (score 0):

To open a URL/website you do the following:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Here's the documentation of [Intent.ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW).